# Разработка json restful api на php

Tags: php, веб-программирование, asp.net, api, rest

Как подойти к созданию JSON RESTful API на PHP, если делать все с нуля. Стоит ли использовать реализации MVC?

**Иначе**, какие **фреймворки** порекомендуете?

1. Slim ....
2. Zend framework
3. Laravel
4. Silex
5. Phalcon
6. и.т.д

**Стоит ли использовать**
 ASP.NET Web API?

**Примерная рабочая Схема** (*не очень хорошая, как пишут*):

**1.WebServer(хостинг)**

```
WebServer(хостинг) - index.php/users/
                           userInfo.php
                           createAccount.php
                           /..../
```

WebServer - на нём располагаются файлы,  распределенные по директориям, и обращаясь по uri к какому-ту файлу, получим ответ, в формате JSON.

2.**Получение данных от WebServer**:

Если нам нужны какие-то данные, посылаем запрос , допустим GET в формате JSON, на определённое uri , допустим www.site.com/users/userInfo.php?infoALL=RIKO.  В ответ, мы получаем данные в формате JSON из MySQL СУБД.

**ВОПРОС** как это правильно сделать? 
По вышеописанной схеме, конечно, все будет работать, но этот вариант слишком примитивен, и в дальнейшем при его использовании, обязательно будут проблемы.

Comment: Я использую Silex и пакеты композера. Laravel имеет готовый REST компонент, в Симфони тоже готовый есть.

Comment: я бы использовал Slim framework + firebase

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент я пишу API для себя. `FrontEnd` которого состоит с обработки JSON, а `BackEnd` - на РНР. Для бэкенда я использую [CakePHP 3.x](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html).

Пути можно проставить кастомно. А можно использовать стандартные. К примеру:
У Вас есть контроллер `API`, в котором есть метод `login`. То отправить запрос на данный контроллер к методу `login` можно по следующему адресу :

```
$.post('/api/login', data, function (json) {
    // Обработка ответа
})
```

На счёт использования **MVC** - да, и только. Вы не пожалеете.
Не стоит писать 100500 своих связок или писать свой фреймворк. Используйте готовые. Учите и применяйте знания на действии.

Answer (score 1):

1. PHP или ASP использовать зависит от платформы где все будет разворачиваться дабы потом не мучать веб сервер настройками поддержки того или иного языка.
2. Если платформу можно выбрать любую, то при выборе между PHP или ASP, выберите то с чем вы лучше знакомы и умеете работать.
3. Разницы в реализации ваших задач на PHP или ASP не будет никакой, потому как оба языка прекрасно реализуют API. Тут важно учесть что будет дальше, PHP и ASP имеют свои особенности и плюсы. Подумайте кто потом будет поддерживать это? Есть ли специфичный функционал? На каком языке больше готовых решений или примеров?
4. MVC ? Фреймворки ? Вы серьезно ? У вас View одно и тоже - JSON данные. И вообще, если задача только вынимать и отдавать данные из SQL, нужны ли фреймворки или городить огород MVC стиля?
5. Задумайтесь лучше над вопросом REST или SOAP. Спросите меня, если не понимаете о чем я